# Best way to implement .lastChild using Prototype or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Currently we are using prototype and jQuery as our js frameworks. Right now, jQuery is set to $j() to prevent conflicts from prototype.

In the past, we've used a lot of prototype's Element.down(), Element.next(), and Element.previous() to traverse the DOM. However, I need a simple way to retrieve the last child element. I know i can loop through an array by using Element.childElements() but I would like something inline that reads cleanly and can be pipelined.

Just thought I would ask before I go reinventing the wheel. Here's a snippet of code that has lastChild in it that needs to be replaced:

```
_find : function(rows, address) {
        var obj = null;
        for (var i=0; i < rows.length && obj == null; i++) {
            if (rows[i].down().className == 'b')
                obj = this._find(rows[i].lastChild.down().down().childElements(), address);
            else if (rows[i].lastChild.getAttribute('tabAddress') == address)
                return rows[i].lastChild;
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Guys, note that the selector functions return arrays of elements (not single elements), so you must adddress the element in the result array by index: [0].

Code in prototype

```
//if you only have the id of the parent
var lastChild = $$("#parent :last-child")[0]; 
//or
//if you have the actual DOM element
var lastChild = $(element).select(":last-child")[0];
```

Code in Jquery

```
//if you only have the id of the parent
var lastChild = $("#parent :last-child")[0]; 
//or
//if you have the actual DOM element
var lastChild = $(":last-child", element)[0];
```

Code in plain vanilla javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("parent");
var lastChild = element.childNodes[element.childNodes.length - 1];
```

Also note that these can return null if the parent element has no child nodes.

- [Some info on the CSS :last-child selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it has always worked for me in jQuery

```
var lastChild = $("#parent :last-child");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild

Comment: What if the parent doesn't have an ID value?

Comment: Yes I think that snipet will get the element with id of parent not the parent element

Answer (score 1):

Using Prototype you can use the [$$](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) utility function which supports most of the CSS3 syntax:

```
var lastChild = $$(".b:last-child")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this while searching the web to answer their question, with Prototype you can do:

```
Element.childElements().last();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else's reference who still uses Prototype, You can add custom element methods:

`Element.addMethods({ ... });`

I added these two among others:

```
first: function(element) {
    element = $(element);
    return element.childElements()[0];      
},
last: function(element) {
    element = $(element);
    var i = element.childElements().size() - 1;
    return element.childElements()[i];
}

var first = $('foo').first();
var last = $('foo').last();
```

The `Element.first()` method is sort of redundant, I use it for cleaner-looking code when chaining.

Make sure you `reutrn element` to enable chaining.